# Identifying and Non identifying Vs Weak and Strong

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

What is the difference between identifying and non- identifying relationship and how are they different from strong and weak relationships?

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Relationship (ER) modelling an entity is deemed to be a *weak entity* if any part of its primary key consists of a reference to another entity. Put another way, an entity is weak if its primary key includes any foreign key attributes, otherwise the entity is *strong*.

A relationship where a referencing (foreign key) attribute is part of a primary key is called an *identifying relationship*, otherwise it is *non-identifying*. In other words a weak entity is one that is subject to an identifying relationship.

Note that these are ER modelling concepts, not relational model concepts. In relational database terms such concepts aren't especially useful because the relational model makes no distinction between them.